# Set HTML Element Attribute for Field that is Dynamically Created

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set an attribute for an element in a form that doesn't exist until a selection is made in a previous element. For instance, a person selects a timezone and then a calendar field becomes visible. Prior to selecting the timezone, the calendar field does not exist whatsoever. I'd like to set the "max" attribute for the calendar field and am having a bit of a challenge building an event listener to accomplish this.

In this case, the timezone field is as follows:

```
<select
  id="mktoTimeZone"
  name="mktoTimeZone"
  aria-describedby="ValidMsgmktoTimeZone"
  aria-labelledby="LblmktoTimeZone InstructmktoTimeZone"
  class="mktoField mktoHasWidth mktoRequired mktoValid"
  aria-required="true"
  style="width: 300px;"
  aria-invalid="false"
>
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="Eastern">Eastern</option>
  <option value="Central">Central</option>
  <option value="Mountain">Mountain</option>
  <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
  <option value="Pacific">Pacific</option>
  <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
  <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
</select>
```

When a selection a made, this element is created:

```
<input
  id="mktoDaytobeContacted"
  name="mktoDaytobeContacted"
  maxlength="2000"
  aria-describedby="ValidMsgmktoDaytobeContacted"
  aria-labelledby="LblmktoDaytobeContacted InstructmktoDaytobeContacted"
  type="date"
  class="mktoField mktoDateField mktoHasWidth mktoRequired mktoValid"
  aria-required="true"
  style="width: 300px;"
  aria-invalid="false"
>
```

The parent element/form to which both of these elements belong to is as follows:

```
<form
  class="mktoForm mktoHasWidth mktoLayoutAbove"
  id="mktoForm_2806"
  novalidate="novalidate"
  style="
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    width: 511px;
  "
>
```

I currently have the following JS that errors out:

```
respondToVisibility = function(element, callback) {
    var options = {
        root: document.documentElement
    };
    var observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
          callback(entry.intersectionRatio > 0);
        });
    }, options);
    observer.observe(element);
};

respondToVisibility(document.getElementById('mktoDaytobeContacted'), visible => {
    const feedbackEl = document.getElementById('mktoForm_2806');
    if(visible) {
        /* Update the getTime() leading integer to increment blackout range
           ex: "getTime()+(100" pushes date to 100 days */
        var dateCutoff = new Date(new Date().getTime()+(90 * 86400000));
        var day = ('0' + dateCutoff.getDate()).slice(-2);
        var month = ('0' + dateCutoff.getMonth() + 1).slice(-2);
        var year = dateCutoff.getFullYear();
        var formattedDateCutoff = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

        // Set Max for date type element
        document.getElementById('mktoDaytobeContacted')
            .setAttribute('max', formattedDateCutoff);
    }
});
```

The error I receive on page load is as follows:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'IntersectionObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.`

I suspect that this is due to this particular function requiring that the element be already created and simply not visible. I'm pretty new to JavaScript. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using our browser dev tools do you get any errors on the console, in particular document.getElementById('mktoDaytobeContacted') is only going to give you an element if an element with that id already exists, if not observe is likely to fail as you suspect.

Comment: The only relevant error I get is for the observe.

Comment: Are you sure there's an element with this ID: `mktoDaytobeContacted`? Letters are the right case and spelling?